# How to run an AWS Lambda Layer in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I would like to run a Docker container to see what is in a public Lambda Layer.

Following the [aws sam layers docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-layers.html) using a sam app with only the pytorch layer  I produced the Docker tag then I tried pulling the Docker image which fails with pull access denied / repo may require auth.

I did try `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email` to auth correctly though still couldn't access the image.

So I think the issue maybe that I am not authorised to pull the image of the lambda layer or the image doesn't exist. It is not clear to me

Alternatively it would be good to download the public Lambda Layer and then I could use https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda to inspect it

**More context about what I tried**

So the Lambda Layer I would like to investigate is:

```
arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:934676248949:layer:pytorchv1-py36:1
```

The docker tag I prodcued is:

```
python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8
```

Then I tried pulling the Docker image with:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash samcli/lambda:python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8 -i
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/samcli/lambda:python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8 -i
```

Which both failed with the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for samcli/lambda, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick potential answer (I've not read the links you provided as I am not at my computer), given you mentioned `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email` I am assuming you are trying to pull a docker image from AWS's docker repository service.

The line `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash samcli/lambda:python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8 -i`, with default config, will look at docker hubs repository. If you are trying to pull a docker image in AWS I would expect something more like `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/samcli/lambda:python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8 -i` (again not saying that cammand will work but something like it to go along with your aws repo sign in command).

Since https://hub.docker.com/samcli/lambda is a 404 I suspect this is one of those occasions the error message is exactly right, the repo does not exist.

Comment: I have tried `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/samcli/lambda:python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8 -i` as suggested sadly still didn't work

Comment: Sorry I didnt make it clear that the command won't work, the domain needs the account id and region; this would have been better `<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/samcli/lambda:python3.6-0ffbca5374c4d95e8e10dbba8 -i`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I did use my own account id and specified the region.